# Is this (classical?) exercice missing a hypothesis?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, power-series

A friend just told me about an exercice he was given quite a few years ago, but he wasn't sure wether he remembered all the hypothesis correctly. Does anybody recognize this?

> Let $f$ be a smooth real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ such that for all $n\in\Bbb N,~\sup_{\Bbb R}|f^{(n)}|=1$ and $f(0)=1$, then $f=\cos$.

He wasn't sure wether theose were the exact hypothesis needed for this to work. He noticed that $f$ is automatically a power series with infinite radius of convergence, but wondered wether one ought to impose $f$ to be even, and wether the condition on the suprermums of the derivatives is correct.

**NOTE.** If you know the hypothesis, please post them as an answer, and if you want to post a solution, please hide the text so that one needs to scroll over it to reveal it, thanks!

Comment: Hum... if this is true, it is quite striking, +1. And I wonder in which spheres this is classical. Not mine.

Comment: @Julien I agree :D I have tried a bit, and tried to prove that $f''(0)=-1$ which would be enough, but I don't make any progress, and doubt I'm on the right path.

Comment: I understand that if you can prove $f''(0)=-1$, then you apply this to $-f''$ to find $f^{(4)}(0)=1$ and so on. But you are probably also assuming $f$ even, in which case the result follows clearly. Otherwise, how do deduce it?

Comment: @Julien I'm not assuming it's even, its just that $f'(0)$ must be equal to $0$ for $f$ not to exceed $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$, and if we can show that $f''(0)=-1$ we would be done.

Comment: @julien : Since $f(0) = 1$, then $f(x) - 1$ has the sign of $f'(0)x$ in a neighborhood of $0$ (but it must remain $\le 0$).

Comment: @JoelCohen Thanks. It looks like I forgot $f(0)=1$...

Answer (score 3):

There is a 1980 paper by John Roe titled *A characterization of the sine function*, with the following abstract. I suspect the specific result here follows from Roe's theorem.

> If a function and all its derivatives and integrals are absolutely
>   uniformly bounded, then the function is a sine function with period
>   2π.

http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2081636

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. Do you know a link to the full paper?

Comment: I don't have a link to the paper. (I didn't read it either...) This paper states Roe's result, which is pretty much a longer version of the abstract: http://scholarcommons.sc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1020&context=math_facpub

Comment: If you have a journal subscription, a link to that paper is there. The essence of the approach is to investigate the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. An exponential dampening factor is introduced to make the function $L^1$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Thanks for the sketch of proof. If I asked, it is precisely because I don't have journal subscription...

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong If for any reason you care to invite julien for a private chat, follow this [link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/50985/julien).

Comment: Could somebody provide a little more detail? The article is behind a paywall and I don't really understand the approach suggested by @Christopher A. Wong ...